# prototype of a struct in c

Tags: c, struct, prototype, typedef

I'd like to organize my code in c, so it works a little bit like the `public` and `private` keywords in c++

specifically, I have some functions that will be used as a library in other projects, and I would like to make `public` only the functions that are used by the projects, not the functions necessary for the internal actions

it would be easy if I could have all of them in the same file.c, but my school rules prevent me against that

I hope an example will be clear :

```
(A) struct definition      (B) struct definition
in header.h                in second_file.c
+----------------------+   +----------------------+
| header.h             |   | header.h             |
------------------------   ------------------------
| #ifndef HEADER_H     |   | #ifndef HEADER_H     |
| # define HEADER_H    |   | # define HEADER_H    |
|                      |   |                      |
| typedef struct foo   |   |                      |
| {                    |   |                      |
|   type param_1;      |   |                      |
|   type param_2;      |   |                      |
| } t_foo;             |   |                      |
|                      |   |                      |
| void action_a(void); |   | void action_a(void); |
| void action_b(void); |   | void action_b(void); |
|                      |   |                      |
| #endif               |   | #endif               |
+----------------------+   +----------------------+

+----------------------+   +----------------------+
| first_file.c         |   | first_file.c         |
------------------------   ------------------------
| # include header.h   |   | #include header.h    |
|                      |   |                      |
| // prototypes        |   | // prototypes        |
| void utils_a(void);  |   | void utils_a(void);  |
| void utils_b(void);  |   | void utils_b(void);  |
|                      |   |                      |
|                      |   | // struct prototype  |
|                      |   | t_foo;               |
|                      |   |                      |
| void action_a(void){ |   | void action_a(void){ |
|   // do something;   |   |   // do something;   |
|   // use t_foo;      |   |   // use t_foo;      |
| }                    |   | }                    |
| void action_b(void){ |   | void action_b(void){ |
|   // do something;   |   |   // do something;   |
| }                    |   | }                    |
+----------------------+   +----------------------+

+----------------------+   +----------------------+
| second_file.c        |   | second_file.c        |
------------------------   ------------------------
| # include header.h   |   | #include header.h    |
|                      |   |                      |
|                      |   | typedef struct foo   |
|                      |   | {                    |
|                      |   |   type param_1;      |
|                      |   |   type param_2;      |
|                      |   | } t_foo;             |
|                      |   |                      |
| void utils_a(void) { |   | void utils_a(void) { |
|   // do something;   |   |   // do something;   |
|   // use t_foo;      |   |   // use t_foo;      |
| }                    |   | }                    |
| void utils_b(void) { |   | void utils_b(void) { |
|   // do something;   |   |   // do something;   |
| }                    |   | }                    |
+----------------------+   +----------------------+
```

case `A` works, but not case `B`

as you can see, in both cases (`A` and `B`) the header doesn't include the utils functions, they cannot be used by other functions (unless they include the prototype themselves), the header doesn't include them

I would like to do the same for the struct (which is used in both files.c), because this struct is only a utility for the functions, but has no purpose to be called elsewhere

### EDIT a working example with solution from comments, but its not working (compilation gives me an error)

`header.h`

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
# define HEADER_H

#include <stdlib.h> // malloc()
#include <stdio.h>  // printf()

// CASE A ONLY
// typedef struct  foo {
//     int         param;
// }               t_foo;
// CASE A END

// CASE B ONLY
typedef struct  foo t_foo;
// CASE B END

t_foo   **allocate_foo(void);

#endif
```

`first_file.c`

```
#include "header.h"

int     main(void)
{
        t_foo   **tfoo;

        tfoo = allocate_foo();
        (*tfoo)->param = 1;
        printf("%i\n", (*tfoo)->param);
        return (0);
}
```

`second_file.c`

```
#include "header.h"

// CASE B ONLY
struct  foo {
        int     param;
};
// CASE B END

t_foo   **allocate_foo(void)
{
        static t_foo    *tfoo;

        tfoo = malloc(sizeof(t_foo));
        return (&tfoo);
}
```

case A compiles fine and prints `1`, but case B throw an error at compilation :

```
first_file.c: In function ‘main’:
first_file.c:8:9: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘t_foo {aka struct foo}’
  (*tfoo)->param = 1;
         ^~
```

Comment: Why the second setup is failing?

Comment: I don't know how to do the typedef struct prototype (it's obviously not just `t_foo;`)
I tried lots of different ways but it never works

Comment: ok, so it's something peoples do, I'm glad to hear I'm not trying to do something stupid :) I don't succeed with the opaque data type so far, but I realize it's difficult to work on it because I didn't provide a working example code, so I will edit my question

Comment: I'd say, replace `t_foo;` with `typedef struct foo t_foo;` and put it in the header and then write `struct foo { type param_1; type param_2; }` in either one of the `.c` files

Comment: well, it gives me an error of dereferencing pointer, I'll add the code above

Comment: If you want the implentation of the struct to be private -- you cannot know that it has a member named "param" (`(*tfoo)->param = 1;`). Maybe you need to rework that into something like `setparam(tfoo, 1);` and do the param assignment inside the c file that knows how the struct is implemented.

Comment: @hugogogo `I hope an example will be clear :` How have you generated such a view? Did you typed all the `+----+` characters by hand? What tool did you use?

Comment: @KamilCuk it's just hand typed inside a code block, but I did it in vim, with the ease of visual block mode :)

Comment: @pmg, "**something like `setparam(tfoo, 1);`**", ok, much more like in c++, I'll try it that way

Comment: @pmg it works fine with the `setparam()` approach ;) thx !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual most basic solution is to make public the struct type identifier, but keep the definition private ... aka [opaque pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) ... something like `FILE`

```
/* library.h */
#ifndef LIBRARY_H_INCLUDED
#define LIBRARY_H_INCLUDED

struct foo; // struct foo exists; it's definition is elsewhere
struct foo *newfoo(int);
void printfoo(struct foo *);
void killfoo(struct foo *);

#endif // LIBRARY_H_INCLUDED
```

---

```
/* library.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "library.h"

struct foo { int bar; }; // struct foo has a single member

struct foo *newfoo(int n) {
    struct foo *r = malloc(sizeof *r);
    if (r) r->bar = n;
    return r;
}

void printfoo(struct foo *s) {
    printf("%d\n", s->bar);
}

void killfoo(struct foo *s) {
    free(s);
}
```

---

```
/* main.c */
#include "library.h"

int main(void) {
    struct foo *p = newfoo(42);
    if (p) {
        printfoo(p);
        killfoo(p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: one of the famous examples is the [D-pointer in Qt](https://wiki.qt.io/D-Pointer) which is a kind of [opaque pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer)

Comment: Yeah ,,, "opaque pointer" may be a better term than "opaque data type". Thanks @phuclv